# ROS Answers SE migration: raw disparity?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can see the disparity.

( rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/camera/depth/disparity )

But I know the disparity added colors.

I need raw disparity(?) or not color-disparity.

How can I get the raw disparity?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42142/raw-disparity?/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The disparity is visualized using color to show the user.  The value of the pixels in the image if you iterate across it is the disparity value.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0